# Error in for-loop for simulating data with negative difference scores as rows

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I want to run a for loop to simulate some data, but run into an error.
The general idea is that I want to simulate the formula: (D-A)/K.

D and A can vary between values of 0 and 10. K can vary between values of 0 and 150.
I want an output matrix/dataframe, with the difference for every possible combination of D-A on the rows (21 rows, varying between a value of -10 and +10), for each level of K (150 columns).

I wrote this piece of code:

```
D = c(0:10)
A = c(0:10)
K = c(0:150)

output=matrix(NA)

for (d in 0:10){
  for (a in 0:10){
    for (k in 0:150){
      output[i-j,k]=(D[d]-A[a])/K[k]
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I think because subsetting [i-j] gives a negative row number in some instances (for example D[2] - A[5]). I don't know how to work around this issue. The values of A, D, and K are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: your index calculation gives negative indices, which is not helpful.

I'd avoid loops altogether.  Does this give you what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble() %>% 
        expand(K=1:150, A=0:10, D=0:10) %>% 
        mutate(Y=(D-A)/K)
df
# A tibble: 18,150 x 4
       K     A     D     Y
   <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1     0     0     0
 2     1     0     1     1
 3     1     0     2     2
 4     1     0     3     3
 5     1     0     4     4
 6     1     0     5     5
 7     1     0     6     6
 8     1     0     7     7
 9     1     0     8     8
10     1     0     9     9
# … with 18,140 more rows
```

Note: I've changed the values of `K` since division by `0` is also problematic.

This should give you the value of (D - A) / K for every value of A and D between 0 and 10 and K between 1 and 150.  That's 11 x 11 x 150 = 18150 combinations.